# From where do I find the dialogflow request payload?

Tags: heroku, logging, dialogflow-es

I have a flask based service hosted in Heroku. The endpoint of which is given as a fulfillment in dialogflow. Now I cannot figure out how to capture the request payload which dialogflow triggers everytime I request something.

I tried capturing and logging the same in heroku itself but that does not seem to be working.

The service code is as follows:

```
@app.route('/date/currentdate/<date>', methods = ['POST'])
def postJsonHandler():
    print (request.is_json)
    content = request.get_json()
    logging.warning(content)
    return 'JSON posted'
```

The json which i am getting is:

```
WARNING:root:{'responseId': 'c5115583-e9c5-497a-8a50-1ea07ab02dba-baaf0c1f', 'queryResult': {'queryText': 'send me the asap for 4568999', 'parameters': {'Dashboard': 'ASAP', 'number': 4568999.0}, 'allRequiredParamsPresent': True, 'fulfillmentMessages': [{'text': {'text': ['Hi I can definitely help you out with that.']}, 'platform': 'SKYPE'}, {'text': {'text': ['']}}], 'intent': {'name': 'replaced this', 'displayName': 'ASAP Dashboard'}, 'intentDetectionConfidence': 0.7012109, 'languageCode': 'en'}, 'originalDetectIntentRequest': {'payload': {}}, 'session': 'replaced this'}
```

Comment: with logging.warning(content) i am getting the json in the console log but on copying the same it cannot be parsed as json.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the JSON you're getting? When you say "it cannot be parsed", what error or results are you getting?

Comment: I have added the JSON, actually when I am pasting the same in any json viewer it is showing error in syntax. Also if I want to use any element of the json, eg. content = request.get_json()
    if(content['Dashboard']=="ASAP"):

where Dashboard is present in parameter in the json then I am getting KeyError: 'Dashboard' message

Answer (score 0):

There is diagnostic info section in the agent section [image: dialogflow] which has got all the info related to request and response, it is sometimes not visible if there is pop up on the top of page, in my case it was the v2 getting outdated banner; on closing it the diagnostic info became visible.